# Forcing the Twitter Epi Library to post a status update even if it's a duplicate of the last tweet

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using the epi libs from: https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/

When trying to post a twitter update I am met with an issue where if the tweet has already previously been made it errors out, I want it post it again and ignore the fact that it's a duplicate.

I thought that the code `$twitter->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $tweet));` would forcefully make the tweet every time but it doesn't for me :/

Anyone know why or can give me an example of some working code / can fix this for me?

Here's a copy of my code snippit:

```
try {
    $twitter->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $tweet));
} catch (EpiTwitterForbiddenException $e) {
    $msg = json_decode($e->getMessage());
    if ($msg->error != 'Status is a duplicate.') {
    //throw $e;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it post it again and ignore the fact that it's a duplicate.

It's not possible yet, You can not post the same tweet twice, that's twitter feature, look: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3714

Comment: just open a new question, it might be helping. By the way, thanks for accapting the answer. :)